# Asynchronously set images in tableview

Tags: ios, image, asynchronous, tableview

I have a `TableView` using custom cells. I initially was setting grabbing an image from a URL in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *dictObject = [places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text  = [dictObject valueForKey:@"PlaceTitle"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images1.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Mario-Kart-Wii-Items-mario-kart-1116309_600_600.jpg"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}
```

but this was making my TableView scroll laggy. Once I removed the image fetch, it scrolled fine, so I know this is my problem.

My question is: how can I asynchronously fetch this image and set it in my cell? Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Look at `NSURLSession`, `NSURLConnection`, and friends.

Comment: Have you looked into sd_webimage? It will take care of downloading and setting images and also caches..

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: This may helps you...[MJTableImageSwift](https://github.com/JaleelNazir/MJTableImageSwift). Change it to Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Have a cache containing images. Either just in memory, better on disk.

Step 2: When you need an image, call a method which either returns an image  from the cache, or returns a default image and starts a download.

Step 3: When a download finishes, add the image to the cache. Then find out which rows need the image. Reload all the rows that reload the image.

The download should be done asynchronously using GCD. I would really recommend that you add the download code into a separate, reusable method so that you can handle download errors. Even if you don't do it now, you will do it later.

Comment: When you set an image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` does it download that image each time the view is shown on the screen (the way I was doing it, I mean)? Or only once?

Answer (score 0):

dataWithContentsOfURL is a synchronous method rather than asynchronous,as 
[Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:) described.

> This method is ideal for converting data:// URLs to NSData objects, and can also be used for reading short files synchronously. If you need to read potentially large files, use inputStreamWithURL: to open a stream, then read the file a piece at a time.

In order to asynchronously load image,especially in tableViewCell,try use 3rd part Library [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside your tableviews cellforindexpath

```
 NSURLRequest *req =[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourimageurl.com"]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
    }
     else{
            //error
   }


}];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create UIImageView Class File (i named it to MJTableImageView).

in **MJTableImageView.h** File

```
    @interface MJTableImageView : UIImageView< NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate >

    {
    NSMutableData *imageData ;
    long long expectedLength;
    NSURLConnection *currentConnection;
    NSString *File_name;

    }
    @property(nonatomic,readonly)UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
    @property(nonatomic)BOOL showLoadingIndicatorWhileLoading;

    -(void)setImageUrl:(NSURL *)imageUrl fileName:(NSString *)name;

    @end
```

in **MJTableImageView.m** File

```
-(void)setImageUrl:(NSURL *)imageUrl fileName:(NSString *)name
{
    // discard the previous connection
    if(currentConnection)
    {
        [currentConnection cancel];
    }

    File_name = name;

    //reset current image
    self.image = nil;


//    if(_showLoadingIndicatorWhileLoading)
//    {
        //show the loading indicator

        if(!_loadingIndicator)
        {
            CGFloat width = self.bounds.size.width*0.5;

            _loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width-width)/2, (self.bounds.size.height-width)/2, 25.0 , 25.0)];
            _loadingIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
            _loadingIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = width*0.1;
        }
        [self startLoadingIndicator];
//    }

    // initialize the placeholder data
    imageData = [NSMutableData data];


    // start the connection
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl];
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;

    currentConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];



}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //if the image view is reused in a table view for example to load another image  previous image is discarded
    if(connection != currentConnection)
    {
        [connection cancel];
        [self cleanUp];
        return;
    }

    // append new Data
    [imageData appendData:data];



    // show the partially loaded image
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    expectedLength = response.expectedContentLength;
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // clean up
    [self cleanUp];

}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // show the full image
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    NSString *filename = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/%@", File_name];
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:imageData]);
    [data writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];

    // clean up
    [self cleanUp];
}
-(void)cleanUp
{
    // clean up
    imageData = nil;
    [self stopLoadingIndicator];
}
-(void)startLoadingIndicator
{
    if(!_loadingIndicator.superview)
    {
        [self addSubview:_loadingIndicator];
    }
    [_loadingIndicator startAnimating];
}
-(void)stopLoadingIndicator
{
    if(_loadingIndicator.superview)
    {
        [_loadingIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [_loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

I am using StoryBoard so i add ImageClass(MJTableImageView) file to UItableviewcell ImageView and set tag number to it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.MJTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MJImageCell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {

    }
    UILabel *appName = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    appName.text = [dict valueForKey:@"trackName"];

    MJTableImageView *imageview = (MJTableImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    NSString *url = [dict valueForKey:@"artworkUrl60"];

    NSString *filename = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/%@",[dict valueForKey:@"trackName"] ];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
    if(data)
    {
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
    else
    {
        [imageview setImageUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:url] fileName:[dict valueForKey:@"trackName"]];
    }
    return  cell;
}
```

For More details see [Github Project MJTableImageSwift](https://github.com/JaleelNazir/MJTableImageSwift) it is in Swift.